# How to use EF Core Cosmos provider with ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

Following [this simple EF Core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1) written by Microsoft, everything runs fine. Students can be created, read, updated, and deleted.

Below are the steps attempting to switch to Cosmos DB instead of SQL Server:

**Installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos` package.**

**Replaced the following code in Startup.cs**

```
// This block removed
services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

// This block added
services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
options.UseCosmos(
    "https://example.documents.azure.com:443/",
    "Example primary key",
    "EFCoreTest"
));
```

When running the application now, the following error is returned when attempting to create a student:

> NotSupportedException: The 'ID' on entity type 'Student' does not have a value set and no value generator is available for properties of type 'int'. Either set a value for the property before adding the entity or configure a value generator for properties of type 'int'.

What is the correct way to use Cosmos DB instead of SQL Server using EF Core 3.1?

Comment: It seems the Cosmos has identity insert set to ON somewhere

Comment: @Qudus where would that be set?

Comment: Does adding the attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to the `Student.Id` property work?

Comment: That did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting this in your context where you can override the onmodelcreating e.g. (x stands for your entity)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
modelBuilder.Entity<x>().Property(t => t.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); }
```

That did the trick for me when auto generating id's on add